# prove or disprove about piecewise continuous‏ functions

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, piecewise-continuity

just some proves or disproves, I can really use some help/clues with:

1. If F is piecewise continuous‏ in $ [-\pi,\pi]$ then it belongs to $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$

- I don't think its true, maybe $cot(x)$ disprove it? not sure.

2. If F belongs to $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$ then F is piecewise continuous‏.

- I think its true but don't know how to prove it in general.

3. If f is continuous‏ in $R$ then f belongs to $L_1(R)$

thank you!

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\cot x$ is not a counter-example because it is not defined on the whole of $[-\pi,\pi]$. But you can define a piecewise continuous function $f$ that equals $\cot x$ where that is defined, and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. False, take any function with a vertical asymptote that diverges sufficiently quickly
2. False, take any measurable bounded non-piecewise continuous function on $[-\pi, \pi]$, e.g. the characteristic function of the irrationals in $[-\pi, \pi]$ or the unit fraction indicator function.
3. False, take any non-null constant function.

Comment: For 2, changing a function at a single point also doesn't change whether it's piecewise continuous. An explicit counterexample, such as the unit fraction indicator function, might be wise.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answers. quick question: about number 1, is my counter example good ? (cot(X))

Comment: @LtSten Can you please explain the use of the indicator function? in what range I define it so the function won't count as  piecewise continuous?

Comment: @LtSten yeah, my bad. I jumped directly to point 3, and forgot about the piecewise condition

Comment: @omerkatz yes, $\cot(x)$ is not in $L_2$. Also, I believe LtSten meant the characteristic function of the set $\{ 1/n : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It's not piecewise continuous because it has a countable infinity of discontinuities (at each $1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$).

Comment: "2. [...] take any bounded non-piecewise continuous function...":  not _any_ such function. It has to be in $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @TonyK ok, let me add that the function has to be on $[-\pi, \pi]$...

Comment: That's not enough. If we assume the Axiom of Choice, not every bounded function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is square-integrable. See [Non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set).